# How does malloc work within wrapper function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc

I have a question dedicated to:

```
void* malloc (size_t size);
```

In the regular example that can be found on millions of sites over the internet it's shown that the right way to use `malloc` is the following:

```
int main()
{
   int* num;
   num = malloc(sizeof(int));

   *num = 10;
   printf("Value = %d\n", *num);
   
   free(num);

   return 0;
}
```

But If I want to allocate memory within a function and use it in main like below, then the only option is to implement the function the following way:

```
void func_alloc(int** elem, int num_value)
{
    *elem = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **elem = num_value;
}

int main()
{
    int* num;
    func_alloc(&num, 10);
    free(num);

    return 0;
}
```

I assumed by mistake, that such code as below would work:

```
void func_alloc(int* elem, int num_value)
{
    elem = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *elem = num_value;
}

int main()
{
    int* num;
    
    func_alloc(num, 10);
    free(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please explain or maybe give a link to resource with explanation why does it work only this way?

I really cannot understand why do I need double pointer as an input parameter and why in the other case it comes to "segmentation fault"...

Thank in advance ;)

Comment: *"the only option"* - Not quite. You can always return the pointer, rather than take an output parameter.

Comment: Because C uses [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

Comment: C passes arguments by value. In the last snippet `elem` is just a local variable. Changing it has no effect on `num` in `main`. So `free(num)` is trying to free a pointer that hasn't been assigned a value. Enable the compiler warnings, and the compiler will tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

> *I assumed by mistake, that such code as below will work.*

In C, the arguments are passed by value, when you pass a pointer as an argument of a function, you are passing the value of the pointer, basically a copy of it, not the pointer itself, `malloc` will change the value of that pointer, but since what you passed was a copy, that is what's changed, not the original pointer, that one remains unchanged.

---

In the second code snippet, the working code, `*elem = malloc(sizeof(int));` broadly means make this pointer `elem` point to this valid memory address given to me by `malloc`(assuming it succeeds), the value of the pointer to the pointer `elem` which you passed as an argument remains unchanged, it being a copy doesn't matter because it's not changed, it's still the same address that was passed as argument, the address of the pointer `num` which is now pointing to the memory location given by `malloc`.

`**elem = num_value` means store `num_value` in the address stored in the pointer where `elem` is pointing to, which is where `num` is pointing to, which is the new memory block previously given by `malloc`.

---

That being said, it's not the only option, you can use a local pointer, return it and assign it to another local pointer in the caller side, this is still a copy, but it's a copy of the changed pointer:

```
int *func_alloc(int num_value)
{
    int *elem = malloc(sizeof *elem); //more idiomatic

    if(elem == NULL){        // check for allocation errors
        perror("malloc" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *elem = num_value;
    return elem;
}

int main()
{
    int* num = func_alloc(10);
    free(num);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

**Footnote:**

In the third code snippet, freeing `num`, given that it is uninitialized is a bad idea, I assume you know as much, nonetheless I thought I'd mention it. This may be the reason for the *segfault* you experienced, whatever garbage value `num` has will be assumed to be valid memory address, and `free` will try to deallocate it, doing this will invoke undefined behavior. If it was NULL, it's a different story, it's well defined behavior (execept in some very old standars). Initializing variables when they are declared is, in most cases, a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

A commented explanation :

```
void func_alloc(int* elem, int num_value)
{
    /* elem points to address gave by malloc, let's say 0x12345678 */
    elem = malloc(sizeof(int));

    /* at address 0x12345678 you have now your num_value */
    *elem = num_value;

    /* end of the function. Changes made to parameters passed by value are lost */
}

int main()
{
    int* num;
    
    /* num is a pointer to an address you could not have write access to, you actually don't know */

    func_alloc(num, 10);
    /* As C arguments are passed by value, changes made into the function are lost */

    /* You try to free num which is still a pointer to an address you potentially have no access to => SEGFAULT */
    free(num);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Not shown in this example, but it is good practice to always check that pointer returned by malloc is not NULL, otherwise you should exit without trying to assign a value to the pointer.

Answer (score -1):

If you have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int x)
{
    x = 9;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    foo(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

you probably don't expect the value of `a` in `main()` to change just because `foo()` assigned to `x`, right? It doesn't change, because parameters are assigned by value. The variables `x` in `foo()`, and `a` in `main()` are two different variables.

The same applies in your code. `elem` in `func_alloc()` is a different variable from `num` in `main()`, and assigning to the former doesn't change the value of the latter. The fact that these two are of type `int *`, and not e.g. just `int`, makes no difference in this.

That said, you can also return the pointer you got from `malloc()`, e.g.

```
int *alloc_int(int value)
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = value;
    return p;
}
```

(not that it seems to make much sense for a mere `int`.)